# no android tutorials are working on my android device

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PC & the device are in the same network. I set the correct IP. But when i opened the app i see a toast CameraTutorial shutdown before i press connect button.
Its very weird problem I have been facing.
Please let me know if you have solution for this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197602/no-android-tutorials-are-working-on-my-android-device/) by [stark](https://answers.ros.org/users/20255/stark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On your PC, You should have done the following:

`export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://<your-pc-IP>:11311`

`export ROS_IP=<your-pc-IP>`

and then when you use your android device, try connecting with

**connect:** `http://<your-pc-IP>:11311`

It should work! hope this helps.

mk

---

Originally posted by [MKI](https://answers.ros.org/users/8136/mki/) with karma: 246 on 2014-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0